# Instagram API with more than 20 images

Tags: image, instagram, instagram-api

I wanted to ask you, if there is any possibility to get more than 20 full-res images from Instagram, using the API.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: '2201292293',
    clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
    accessToken:`'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN',
    limit: '364',
    sortBy: 'most-liked',
    template: '<a href="{{image}}" class="popup"><img src="{{image}}"></a>{{likes}}',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution'
});
feed.run();
</script>
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what kind of api do you use? Which endpoint do you use? What have you already tried? There should be `limit` or something like this.

Comment: @JozefCipa I use the Instagram API (Instagram.com/developer)

Comment: @JozefCipa I also use instafeed.js to Display it on my website, there I wrote "limit: 364"...

Comment: Is there really more than 20 images? I don't know what do you actually want to do. You want to get images by user or by hashtag or how? Please show your code too.

Comment: @JozefCipa The code of my Website is situated in the question now. What I want to do is: I want instafeed.js to show my posts (user) on my Website, but Instagram allows you only to post 20 images. So I want to know if there is a possibility to show more than 20 images.

Comment: Have you tried the code below?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It may be caused by pagination.

Add

```
<button id="load-more">
  Load more
</button>
```

to your html. Every time you click on the button, `feed.next()` will be called and fetches more images if they exist.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var loadButton = document.getElementById('load-more');
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '2201292293',
        clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
        accessToken:`'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN',
        limit: '364',
        sortBy: 'most-liked',
        template: '<a href="{{image}}" class="popup"><img src="{{image}}"></a>{{likes}}',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution'

        // every time we load more, run this function
        after: function() {
            // disable button if no more results to load
            if (!this.hasNext()) {
                loadButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        },
    });

    // bind the load more button
    loadButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        feed.next();
    });

    // run our feed!
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Try this code.